# meaning of N-bit encryption

Tags: encryption

If we talk for example about256-bit encryption, does that mean that data is encrypted individually in blocks of that many bits (so for example if bit 260 of my unencrypted data changes, I would only need to re-encrypt bits 256-511) or does that simply mean that whatever the encryption key is, it is 256-bit long? Or something completely else?

Answer (score 1):

"N-bit" encryption, refers to the bit length of the key material use to encrypt the data. i.e. the literal, total number of `1`s & `0`'s one needs to represent the key.

I notice folks tend to confuse bit-length of keys, with bit-strength of the crypto system.

The bit strength of the crypto system is a different concept which represents the key space you'd need to brute force (algorithm agnostic) to crack the crypto system itself.

Sometimes key bit-length == system bit-strength, other times not.

Example:

AES-128 crypto system, uses `128`-bit key-length, and has a ~`128`-bit bit-strength.

ECC-256 crypto system, uses `256`-bit key-length, and has a ~`128`-bit bit-strength.

Answer (score 0):

> If we talk for example about256-bit encryption, does that mean that data is encrypted individually in blocks of that many bits (so for example if bit 260 of my unencrypted data changes, I would only need to re-encrypt bits 256-511) or does that simply mean that whatever the encryption key is, it is 256-bit long? Or something completely else?

There are lots of confusion here.

- **Block ciphers:** Block ciphers operates on blocks. For example, AES uses 128-bit block size.  For a block cipher, you need to use a [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), like archaic ECB, CBC, OFB, CBC, and CTR and some modern like GCM and SIV. Depending on the mode of operation if you need to update a bit you may only re-encrypt a block like in ECB and CTR or you have to re-encrypt rest as in CBC or re-encrypt all like GCM and SIV.
- **Stream Cipher:** Stream ciphers mostly operate on bits. Some examples are A5/1, E0. A recent one ChaCha20 with 512-bit state size. If you need to change a bit in the plaintext you need only re-encrypt the bit if the stream cipher it bit based otherwise only affected blocks. Of course, remember that this can be valid only there is no authentication over the message or encrypted data.

  In short, the mode of operation determines the re-encryption. One should prefer the modern encryption modes since they provide [Authenticated encryption (AE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption)
- **Key size** Key size is determined by the algorithm itself. For AES it has 128,192, and 256- bit key sizes. A5/1 has 64-bit E0 has varied but usually 128-bit, and ChaCha20 has 128 and 256 keys sizes.
- **The effective key length** Although a cipher designed with x-bit key, due to the attacks the effective key length can be lower than the designed. For example, E0 has 38-bit effective key length.

Usually, AES is written  AES128 or AES-128 to indicate the applied key size. There is no confusion here since we already know that AES has 128-bit block size.